# Joining 2 SQL tables, split rows into new columns

Tags: php, mysql, join, split, multiple-columns

**The database structure is as follows for table1:**

```
id | name | total
```

sample data is as follows:

```
1 | Anna  | 100,00€
2 | Peter | 1000,00€
3 | John  | 10,00€
```

**The database structure is as follows for table2:**

```
id | code | value
```

sample data is as follows:

```
1 | Tax 24%  | 20,00€
1 | Tax 14%  | 2,00€
2 | Tax 24%  | 200,00€
2 | Tax 14%  | 20,00€
2 | Tax 24%  | 2,40€
here might also be sales with 0% and 9% tax
```

How i want the sql php statement to show the results in a html table:

```
 id | name | Tax with 24% | Tax with 14% | Tax with 9% | total
*
1  | Anna |    20,00€    |    2,00 €    |     0%      |  100€
```

HOW CAN I WRITE THIS IN MYSQL PHP HTML?

```
<?php  $query = $this->db->query("select
  order_id,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  total,
  (select value from `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` where title='ALV 24%') as tax24,
  (select value from `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` where title='ALV 14%') as tax14,
  (select value from `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` where title='ALV 9%') as tax9
from
  `" . DB_PREFIX . "order`");

$products = array();

// Check if there are any rows returned from the query
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

// Loop through the returned rows for processing
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $products[] = array(
        'order_id' => $result['order_id'],
        'firstname' => $result['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $result['lastname'],
        'tax24' => $result['tax24'],
        'tax14' => $result['tax14'],
        'tax9' => $result['tax9'],
        'total' => $result['total'],
    );
}
} 
foreach ($products as $orders) { ?>
<table class="list">
<tr>
<td><?php print $orders['order_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $orders['firstname'] . " " . $orders['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php print $orders['tax24']; ?></td>
 <td><?php print $orders['tax14']; ?></td>
     <td><?php print $orders['tax9']; ?></td>
     <td><?php print $orders['total']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
?>    
</table>
```

Comment: What do the values in the second table indicate?

Comment: for example how much of 24% tax is payed in the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part's pseudo sql:

```
select
      id,
      name,
      (select value from table2 where code='Tax 24%' and table2.id=table1.id) as tax24,
      (select value from table2 where code='Tax 14%' and table2.id=table1.id) as tax14,
      (select value from table2 where code='Tax 9%' and table2.id=table1.id) as tax9
from
      table1
```

And of course you have to query this in php and display properly.

Comment: I agree with you that this is the 'right' way to do it. However i don't think this should be used in a productional system. Relational databases should be used relational and should not be concenated by this type of query.

Comment: Ok, the code is added above, I´m getting this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row<br />Error No: 1242<br />select order_id, firstname, lastname, total, (select value from `oc_order_total` where title='ALV 24%') as tax24, (select value from `oc_order_total` where title='ALV 14%') as tax14, (select value from `oc_order_total` where title='ALV 9%') as tax9 from `oc_order`' in /

Comment: You should add something similar to the subqueries:  `and table2.id=table1.id` (I changed also my answer reflecting this.)

Answer (score 0):

table2.code must contain a value like "24","14","24".. not "Tax 24%"